# Installed SSD and want to boot existing Ubuntu off of original Hard Disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I just installed a new SSD into my laptop and had some questions on how to boot into Ubuntu.

Before I installed my SSD, I had a single HDD with both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu installed on it. When I got my SSD, I only moved my Windows installation to the SSD, and left the Ubuntu installation on the HDD which is now in the secondary hard drive bay in my laptop. Now, I want to boot into my Ubuntu partition but I'm not sure how. When I boot up, if I don't do anything to change the boot device, it boots to Windows. If I try to select the boot device, it shows Ubuntu as installed on my SSD (my guess is that the boot entry got cloned when I was moving Windows). So, if I try to use that boot entry, it gives me an error about not being able to find Ubuntu on hd1.

Any suggestions? Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: A few drive bays are not bootable, just for data. Is yours bootable? Is system UEFI or BIOS? Best to see details. Post link to Summary report  from live installer:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not too familiar with the difference. In my BIOS settings though, I have Legacy mode enabled if that helps. I think that it was originally UEFI but I turned it off but I'm not sure since I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: If it was pre-installed Windows 8 then it was UEFI and will not work in BIOS/CSM mode. Post link to summary report.

Comment: How/where would I get this summary report?

Comment: See my link above to Boot-Repair's summary report.

Comment: @oldfred Sorry it took so long, my internet is slow and I had to download the ubuntu ISO again. Here's the link to the boot summary report http://paste.ubuntu.com/11921343/. Thanks!

Comment: You have an UEFI system, but have grub installed in gpt's protective MBR on sdb. Be sure to always boot in UEFI mode. But you have an HP. They modify UEFI to also use description and only valid description is "Windows". So we have to do a work around.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/346257/install-alongside-windows-8-is-not-working Other work around: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you a gotta do:

When you turn on your computer, watch the screen.  It will likely say something like 'Press F8 for boot menu' or 'Press ESC for startup options'.  Do that, and select your HDD in the boot menu.

Once you've booted into ubuntu, run this command in Terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That will install GRUB on the SSD, which will let you boot to Ubuntu without going through all the motions.

Comment: There is no option to boot to my HDD in that menu though. The options are OS Bootloader, USB drive, Notebook hard drive, and Ubuntu (Crucial MX100). The Ubuntu (Crucial MX100) is the fake entry on my SSD and when I try Notebook hard drive, I get a black screen that says something like `No boot media found. Insert media and press any key to continue`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could I maybe boot into a live usb version of Ubuntu and run that grub install command?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: I think error is from UEFI/BIOS not from grub or Windows.

Comment: ^possibly that.